# daily refresh of MongoDB Collection with Insert and update

Tags: mongodb, pymongo, upsert

I have a MongoDB collection where Data need to refreshed for certain fields every night. The Target collection has 3 extra custom fields which are used by end user input for respective documents.

So when daily refresh happens overnight, the data source can send new documents or updated data of existing documents. The documents can be upto 10,000.

I am using Pymongo and MongoDB to achieve this. My problem, how to identify the which record need to be updated and which record needs to be inserted with those 3 extra custom fields without impacting end user data.

For Example:

Data Source:

```
Manufacture Name       Model        Year    Units
BMW                    5Series      2019      10
BMW                    5Series      2020       5
AUDI                   A4           2020      20 
AUDI                   A7           2019       3
TOYOTA                 COROLLA      2020       5
TOYOTA                 CAMRY        2020       6
HONDA                  ACCORD       2020       10
HONDA                  PILOT        2019       15  
HONDA                  CRV          2019       20
```

Once Loaded, the App table has 1 custom columns (Location) for user input

```
Manufacture Name       Model        Year     Location   Units
BMW                    5Series      2019     London       10 
BMW                    5Series      2020     New York     5  
AUDI                   A4           2020     Melbourne    20
AUDI                   A7           2019     London       3
TOYOTA                 COROLLA      2020     New York     5
TOYOTA                 CAMRY        2020     London       6  
HONDA                  ACCORD       2020     Sydney       10 
HONDA                  PILOT        2019     Tokyo        15
HONDA                  CRV          2019
```

On second day, we get new data as below

```
Manufacture Name       Model        Year    Units
BMW                    5Series      2019      10
BMW                    5Series      2020       **35**
**BMW                    7Series      2020       12**
AUDI                   A4           2020      20 
AUDI                   A7           2019       3
**AUDI                   A6           2019       1**
TOYOTA                 COROLLA      2020       5
TOYOTA                 CAMRY        2020       6
HONDA                  ACCORD       2020       10
HONDA                  PILOT        2019       15  
*HONDA                  CRV          2019       20*       *-- deleted -- in second refresh*
```

The data can be 10,000 records. How to achieve this with Pymongo or MongodB? I wrote the code in PyMongo until the retrieve the source data and store the cursor in dictionary. Not sure how to proceed after this using MongoDB Upsert or bulk write and preserve/update Location column data for existing records and assign NULL values for new records.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

finally this is achieved as below:

```
import pymongo
from pymongo import UpdateOne


# Define MongoDB connection
client = pymongo.MongoClient(server, username='User', password='password', authSource='DBName', authMechanism='SCRAM-SHA-256')

#Source table    
collection2 = db['cars2']

count123 = collection2.count_documents({})

#print("New Cars2 Data - Count before Insert:",count123)

source_cursor = collection2.find()

print("Cars2 - Count in Cursor:",source_cursor.count())

#Target Table    
collection = db['cars']

tgt_count = collection.count_documents({})

print("Cars Collection - Count before Insert:",tgt_count)

sourcedata = []

#since this is a MongoDB Cursor object, we need push to List using list()
sourcedata = list(source_cursor)

source_cursor.close()



# ADD new columns to the Data before inserting in MongoDB
for item in sourcedata:    

    item['Location'] = None        
    item['last_refresh'] =  datetime.now()


#sourcedata = source_cursor

ops = []

if tgt_count == 0:

    print("Loading for First time:")
    for rec in sourcedata:        
        #Load Data for first time with new fields
        ops.append( UpdateOne({'name': rec['name'],'model':rec['model']}, {'$set': {'name':rec['name'],'model':rec['model'],'year':rec['year'],'units':rec['units'], 'Location': rec['Location'],'last_refresh':rec['last_refresh']}}, upsert=True))

    #print(ops)

    result = collection.bulk_write(ops)


    print("Inserted Count:", result.inserted_count)
    print("Matched Count:", result.matched_count)
    print("Modified Count:", result.modified_count)
    print("Upserted Count:", result.upserted_count)

elif tgt_count > 0:

    print("Updating the Load:")
    for rec in sourcedata:        
        #No Location field is included to avoid replacing the values of this field by NULL
        ops.append( UpdateOne({'name': rec['name'],'model':rec['model']}, {'$set': {'name':rec['name'],'model':rec['model'],'year':rec['year'],'units':rec['units'], 'last_refresh':rec['last_refresh']}}, upsert=True))

    result = collection.bulk_write(ops)

    print("Inserted Count:", result.inserted_count)
    print("Matched Count:", result.matched_count)
    print("Modified Count:", result.modified_count)
    print("Upserted Count:", result.upserted_count)

 #because I didn’t include “Location” field above, the new UPSERT records DO NOT have “Location” field anymore. So I have to update the collection one more time to include “Location” field        

    nullfld_result = collection.update_many({'Location':None},{ '$set':{'Location':None}})


count2 = collection.count_documents({})

print("Count after Insert:",count2)
```